# Laravel Eloquent select from one table and join first row if there's a match from another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 tables

```
+----+------------+------------+
| id | first_name | date       |
+----+------------+------------+
| 1  | Bob        | 01/01/2019 |
+----+------------+------------+
| 2  | June       | 01/05/2019 |
+----+------------+------------+
```

and

```
+----+--------+---------+------------+
| id | userID | comment | date       |
+----+--------+---------+------------+
| 1  | 1      | Hello   | 02/01/2019 |
+----+--------+---------+------------+
| 2  | 1      | Again   | 02/02/2019 |
+----+--------+---------+------------+
| 3  | 2      | Howdy   | 02/03/2019 |
+----+--------+---------+------------+
```

I'd like to get the result of all users with first_name Bob and append the most recent comment to that result.

I can do

```
$users = SELECT * FROM Users WHERE id = 1
```

then

```
foreach($users as $user){
    $comment = Comment::where("userID", $user->id)->first();
    if($comment != null){
        $user->comments = $comment->$comment;
    }
}
```

However it is very slow if there are a lot of results in $users

Comment: Did my answer help your problem? Else i'm glad to try to fix it :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Eager loading with custom query :

```
User::with(['comments' => function($query){
  $query->latest();
}])->where('first_name','bob')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

An extra relation can do the trick.

```
public function latestComment()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Comment::class)->latest('date');
}
```

Now you can access it with `$user->latestComment`.